# How can a PHP CLI script detect if running in the background?

Tags: php, background, command-line-interface, detection

I am developing a CLI PHP script that can either be executed in the foreground or the background. If running in the foreground I want to be able to interact with the user getting input information. Obviously if the script is launched in the background using the '&' parameter any user interaction should be skipped...

So is there a way for a PHP script to detect that it has been launched in the background?

Comment: I don't know - there may be on system level. But wouldn't it be much, much simpler to just pass a parameter to the script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a C/C++ process know if it runs in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940555/how-can-a-c-c-process-know-if-it-runs-in-background)

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to detect if its running in background. I still didn't find any way to do.

One way could be to traverse process list and check the status of `/usr/bin/php`

The best ways is to use a parameter (say `--daemon`). When this parameter is passed it'll be running in background otherwise it'll print useful information on front-end.

You can create daemon using [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) pear package.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Unix [frequently asked question](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-7.html) (which I found via [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940555/how-can-a-c-c-process-know-if-it-runs-in-background)) that basically claims it cannot reliably be done. One suggestion the article gives is to check whether or not `stdin` is a terminal:

```
sh: if [ -t 0 ]; then ... fi
C: if(isatty(0)) { ... }
```

I agree with Pekka's comment that you should simply provide a parameter to the script. The `-i` (for interactive) option is sometimes used for this express purpose. If that parameter isn't passed, you can assume you're in "automated" mode.