# C code for a Shell to allow process to execute in the background (bash)

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, background

**This is homework**

Hey folks, here's the portion of the assignment I'm working on now:

> A command, with or without arguments, executed in the background using &.
>   For simplicity, assume that if present the & is always the last thing on the line.
>   Example: vi &
>   Details: In this case, your shell must execute the command and return immediately, not 
>   blocking until the command finishes. The distinction must be made between
>   backgrounding a process that does not need interactive input and one that does, e.g., the
>   who command vs. the vi command.
>   Concepts: Background execution, signals, signal handlers, process groups, asynchronous
>   execution.
>   System calls: sigset(), sigaction()
>   Signals: SIGTTOU

So we're writing our "own shell" in C, and the code I've written up to now is working fine. Here are a few snippets so you can see what I'm doing:

```
// Check for ampersand
block = (ampersand(args) == 1);
```

The ampersand function works and returns properly according to my debug statements. Here is where I'm almost positive I actually have to do the backgrounding code, and I'm looking for help here:

```
// Wait for the child process to complete, if necessary
  if(block) {
//If this executes, there IS an ampersand, and should be backgrounded
    printf("Waiting for child, pid = %d\n", child_id);
    result = waitpid(child_id, &status, 0);
  } else {
  //If this gets executed, there is no ampersand, and should not be backgrounded
    result = waitpid(child_id, &status, 0);
  }
```

So now I'm at the point where if I type, say "ls -l &" it'll do the ls -l command, and it'll execute that printf statement. So that's good. If I don't put the & in there, it doesn't do the printf. Also good.

**Million dollar question:**
Once I hit the printf statement, what should I do at that point? Please note that this is an introductory course, and I don't know much beyond the code I've already written. I mean, I know C, but Unix is very new to me.

Thanks in advance, I'll be around to supply more detail if needed :)

Comment: Please study the source code of some simple existing free software shell (like `sash`), and read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ and perhaps use `strace` on some *existing* shell. You probably want to `fork` ...

Comment: And therefore checking to see how something like 'sash' does it? Thanks!

Comment: Knowing unknown thing is best rather than asking for code. Hope You have ability to that.see [simple implementation of shell](http://rik0.altervista.org/snippets/csimpleshell.html)

Comment: @Joe Flagged for completely unhelpful. I don't know this Unix command stuff. I know how to code in C, though.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you learn `C`. I would think people would typically learn `C` in a Unix environment. Even on Windows many people use Cygwin.

Comment: @Joe I learned it alongside Java, and just wrote stuff in Xcode. Never done Terminal stuff before now.

Comment: @Joodoo - the point seems to be you need to familiarize yourself with unix before you try to duplicate it (in this case, the shell)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Care to lend a hand with strategies to familiarize myself with it? That statement alone doesn't help much.

Comment: I think you don't even understand what "background" means even though it's explained in the assignment. It means you should NOT call `waitpid()` to wait for the command to complete, since this will block the shell. You must wait until you get a SIGCHLD signal, and then call `wait()` to collect the termination status.

Comment: @Barmar Ohhhhhh, see now that makes good sense. I'll go read up on SIGCHLD :) If you'd care to put that in an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Joodoo Explore [this Code](http://www.ladweb.net/src/ladsh4.c.html) It is very systematic and excellent code (cover all what you wants), If you can either purchase or download the book: [Linux  Application Development](http://www.ladweb.net/src/) In this book code is explained step by step. The assignment is very good Best example to implement IPC using PIPE (if you get soft copy share a link)

Comment: Do you have to implement foregrounding (`fg`) the process?  This might be informative, it describes how a process detects if it is running in the background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940555/how-can-a-c-c-process-know-if-it-runs-in-background

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I have a `function exec_cmd_with_child(\*params*\)`, which will take care of executing the command with appropriate arguments. This function needs to be called from both if and else.

The only difference we have is. inside `if(block)` you will not call wait as the parent process should not wait for the command to execute. Whereas inside `else` you will have to call wait which means the parent will wait till the command executes and will not ask for the next command.

Well, there are plenty of things to take care of if you want to bring back to process in the foreground but if not asked for that, then you are good to go.